# Error while predicting value from saved model

Tags: python, joblib

My friend saved a decision tree model using joblib.dump(). But when I tried to predict using some data from the saved model, I got the following error. Can anyone advise as to why this is happening? My friend and I have the same versions of all required libraries

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    classifier = joblib.load('saved_model.pkl')
  File "C:\Users\naiks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "C:\Users\naiks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\naiks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pickle.py", line 1210, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\naiks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pickle.py", line 1587, in load_reduce
    stack[-1] = func(*args)
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 607, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'
```

Comment: there is no way to reproduce error, because there is no even code provided. Improve Your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a 32 bit version of python, whereas the machine on which the model was trained was using 64 bit python. Hence the buffer size was different, resulting in the error